# Populate Table View Sections with CoreData and Array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I want to populate my Table View with a bunch of folders(similar to the folder structure screen of the Apple Notes App). I want the first item in the TV to be a cell that leads to a combination of all the contents from the other folders. I can display all the folders but am having trouble trying to work out how to display the 'combo contents' folder. All the individual folders are made on CoreData and are being fed through a NSFetchedResultsController.

I created an array of just a single folder instance to use as the object for the combo folder. I have the following code to try and create 2 sections (1 for the combo, the other for the individual folders) but at the moment it will only show whatever I put in case 0. Am I going about this the right way?

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
switch section {
    case 0:
        return comboFolder.count
    case 1:
        return fetchedRC.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "folderCell", for: indexPath) as! FolderTableViewCell

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let folder = comboFolder[indexPath.row]
        cell.updateComboFolder(with: folder)
    case 1:
        let folder = fetchedRC.object(at: indexPath)
        cell.update(with: folder)

    default:
        print("default")
    }
    return cell
 }
```

Comment: For starters, you should return 2 in the `numberOfSections` function

Comment: Yeah, sorry. That was a mistake on my part while I was editing it. Having 2 is causing a crash...

Comment: Where is the crash what is it saying?

Comment: @nambatee 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 1 in section at index 0'

Comment: Do you think this is the way I should be doing this? Do I need to scrap the array all together and do it through CoreData and sorting?

Comment: So the crash is happening because when you call `comboFolder[indexPath.row]` you're asking for an object at index 1 and you only have 1 folder in there so the only index you can use to access it would be 0. So instead of trying to pass individual folders to your cell, you could try passing the entire `comboFolder`, configure the cell with all the folders inside it and then in `didSelectRowAt` check if user selected a row in section 0 and take them to a VC that displays all the combined folders.

Comment: If you don't want to keep a separate `comboFolder` array, just use `fetchedRC.fetchedObjects`. That should give you an array of all your `NSManagedObject` objects (folders). To answer your question about having to do it through Core Data - it looks like you're only looking to have only 1 "combo folder" so modeling it in Core Data would be an overkill, in my opinion.

Comment: Okay, thanks for taking the time to help! At the moment I just created a new struct for the comboFolder array which holds the name and icon (no contents inside it). I made the changes you suggested but it's still only showing the combo folder array and never showing the CD objects. I am getting this CD error when I try to make a new object: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. Is this meaning there's a problem on the CD side. Do I need to tell it somewhere that it's in section 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample project that has your basic setup - https://github.com/nambatee/CombinedFolders1

The trick is to adjust the `indexPath`. You're working with 2 sections but your `NSFetchedResultsController` knows of only 1 section. So you need to be careful not to ask `NSFetchedResultsController` for objects in section at index `1`.

Comment: @a.wip If you wanted to experiment with a full Core Data setup, you could have a separate `FolderGroup` model objects that would have a `name` and a set of `folders`. `Folder` would need to have an additional `groups` property, which would be a `Set<FolderGroup>?`. You would start out with 2 `FolderGroup` objects: “Master Folders” and “Custom Folders” . Then, every time you create a new folder, you’d have to assign it to those 2 groups. That way you could have a fetched results controller with `FolderGroup` in your `FolderTableViewController` with `sectionNameKeyPath` set to `name`.

Comment: @a.wip Because you have 2 groups, you would have 2 sections automatically. This setup would have different trade-offs. Your models would be heavier so fetches would be slower. You’d have to go through more layers of abstraction to get to your notes (group -> folder -> notes).

Comment: Ok, awesome. Thanks heaps for your help!!